# unauthorized response when trying to connect to a website with username and password

Tags: android

I want to connect to rss website that secured with username and password.

I tried to connect with `http://user:pass@rss.com/somepath` but it returns `401` error (unauthorized).

The username and the password are **correct** for sure. When try to log with that path in a browser on my computer it **works**. How can I login to that website to get the data?

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252506/how-to-connect-to-a-website-that-requires-a-username-and-password) is pretty similar to my question. But I need it for `Android` and not for `iOS`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you put the stack trace? May be helpful.

Comment: no stack trace - the response code is 401 instead of 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a `CredentialsProvider` with `UsernamePasswordCredentials` on your `HttpClient`:

```
CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), 
                            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
```